# find pdf from mgf for normal distribution.?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

m.g.f of random variable X is equal to

> e^(t^2)

for -infinity to infinity

what is distribution of X?

Here i suppose it is normal distribution but I am not able to slove.

Comment: Similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343930/calculate-probability-density-function-from-moment-generating-function