# Suppose that X has the moment generating function of the form $M_X(t)=\frac{1}{1-4t}$, $t<\frac{1}{4}$, find probability density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose that X has the moment generating function of the form $M_X(t)=\frac{1}{1-4t}$, $t<\frac{1}{4}$, find probability density function.

Moment generating function is usually given by M(t)= E($e^{tx}$)= $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{tx}*f(x) dx$

How am I supposed to find f(x) then? I just don't get the concept.

Comment: In general, the concept will involve the inverse Fourier transform. But you are in luck, because it seems your MGF matches that of the *exponential* distribution. Have a look at it. Also see here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343930/calculate-probability-density-function-from-moment-generating-function

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I think this is what you mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem

Fourier transform corresponds to the characteristic function of a probability distribution.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, you are right. The Fourier transform comes once we look at the characteristic function, although I think you get that by replacing $t$ by $it$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda>0$. If $X$ has probability density function

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
\lambda e^{-\lambda x} & \textrm{ if } x\geq0 \\
0 & \textrm{ if } x<0
\end{cases}$$
then the moment generating function of $X$ is
$$\begin{align}
M_X(t) &= \int_0^\infty e^{tx}(\lambda e^{-\lambda x})dx \\
&= \lambda \int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda - t)x}dx \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t} \textrm{ for } t<\lambda.
\end{align}$$
Now choose $\lambda = \tfrac14$.